# Problemas con json_encode para una api php y vue fetch

Tags: php, vue.js, api, fetch

Les explico mi problema: Intento hacer una api para un menú "dinámico" es decir `RethinkDB`, `Php` y `VueJs`.
Uso Slim para el router en php y php-rql para conectarme con la db:

```json
"slim/slim": "^4.7",
"slim/psr7": "^1.3",
"slim/http": "^1.2"
"danielmewes/php-rql": "dev-master"
```

index.php `(router)`

```php
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once '../Classes/src/Menu/MainMenu.php';

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

$app = AppFactory::create();
$app->addErrorMiddleware(true, false, false);

$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
  $response->getBody()->write('INICIO');
  return $response;
});

$app->get('/MainMenu/', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
  $inv = new menu;
  $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($inv->GetMainMenu()));
  return $response;
});

$app->run();
```

componente.vue

```
<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      menu: []
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.getMenu()
  },
  methods: {
    getMenu: function (){
      fetch('http://localhost/MainMenu/', {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => (
          this.menu = data,
          console.log(data))
        )
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Al momento de entrar al localhost `(Front End)` en la consola me da el siguiente error:

> `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( in JSON at position 0`

Y al ver la *api* veo que el problema está en "(string)" como aparece en las siguientes imagenes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entiendo que el problema está en (string) pero no se como quitarlo es la primera ves que tengo este error.
Les agradezco de antemano su apoyo.

Comment: Intenta usando [`withJson`](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/response.html#returning-json), por ejemplo, `$response = $response->withJson($inv->GetMainMenu());`

Comment: Gracias Marcos. Pero de hecho sigo teniendo el mismo "error"

Comment: Lo he arreglado! tenía el string en otro archivo que importaba!